# SynapsePay & Django conflicting instances of User issue

Tags: python, django, synapsepay

My name is omar. I am working on a django project that is using the SynapsePay api for monetary transactions. I am getting an issue where I have two instances of the same object(User). Django uses the 'User' object when new users are created within the django application. Synapse uses the 'User' objects when a new user is created within their api. When i try to use the SYnapse api, I am starting to get conflicting uses of the same variable.

In the import statements, when I imported the user from the Synapse Api, I saved the instance of the user as SynapseUser and that is what I am using to interact with the application.

There are parts of the api that are not controllable by me that use the 'User' object within the Api and It is grabbing the wrong object or trying to grab a key that doesnt exist in the key that is being passed.

Here is the all the code I have and the error that I am trying to get...

THe following code is to grab the forms content and test the bank authroization with the api..

[Here is a link to the api github samples.md file](https://github.com/synapsepay/SynapsePayRest-Python/blob/master/samples.md)

Here is the views.py file:

```
import os
from synapse_pay_rest import Client
from synapse_pay_rest import User as SynapseUser
from synapse_pay_rest.models.nodes import AchUsNode

def linkBankLogin(request, form):
    currentUser = loggedInUser(request)
    cd = form.cleaned_data
    bank_name = cd['bank']
    username = cd['username']
    password = cd['password']

    required = {
        'bank_name':'wellsfargo',
        'username':'omarjandali',
        'password':'123123asd'
    }

    ach_us = AchUsNode.create_via_bank_login(SynapseUser, **required)

    ach_us.mfa_verified
```

Here is the error that I am getting when the user submits the linking account form:

```
AttributeError at /link_account/
type object 'User' has no attribute 'client'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/link_account/
Django Version: 1.11.5
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
type object 'User' has no attribute 'client'
Exception Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/synapse_pay_rest/models/nodes/ach_us_node.py in create_via_bank_login, line 39
```

create_via_bank_login is an internal method that is created within the api and not something I can change. How can i get it to grab the SynapseUser

** Update **

THe following code is what is used to look up a user by id:

```
user = User.by_id(client, '...4dc1')
```

so i can do something like this:

```
synapseUser = SynapseUser.by_id(client, '...4dc1')
```

because the code that I just added above worked in returning a created users information

and then instead of:

```
ach_us = AchUsNode.create_via_bank_login(SynapseUser, **required)
```

I can use:

```
ach_us = AchUsNode.create_via_bank_login(synapseUser, **required)
```

** Continued update **

I have the following code to perform what I wanted to integrate:

```
def searchUserSynapse(request):
    currentUser = loggedInUser(request)
    currentProfile = Profile.objects.get(user = currentUser)
    synapse_id = currentProfile.synapse_id

    user = SynapseUser.by_id(clients, str(synapse_id))

    response = user.json
    print(response)
    return user

def linkBankLogin(request, form):
    currentUser = loggedInUser(request)
    cd = form.cleaned_data
    bank_name = cd['bank']
    username = cd['username']
    password = cd['password']

    required = {
        'bank_name':'wellsfargo',
        'username':'omarjandali',
        'password':'123123asd'
    }

    response = searchUserSynapse(request)

    ach_us = AchUsNode.create_via_bank_login(response, **required)

    ach_us.mfa_verified
```

and the new error message is the following:

```
BadRequestError at /link_account/
No exception message supplied
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/link_account/
Django Version: 1.11.5
Exception Type: BadRequestError
Exception Location: 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/synapse_pay_rest/http_client.py in parse_response, line 86
```

how can i find out where the request had the error??

Comment: If my answer helped you solve your problem, you can upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to pass an instance of the class `SynapseUser`, not the class itself.**

The line:

```
ach_us = AchUsNode.create_via_bank_login(SynapseUser, **required)
```

should be:

```
ach_us = AchUsNode.create_via_bank_login(user, **required)
```

where `user` is of type `SynapseUser`

So you need to fetch the `SynapseUser` for the django `User` beforehand:

```
user = SynapseUser.by_id(client, synapse_user_id)
```

You will need to create a method to get the `synapse_user_id` for a django user (in this case `currentUser`)

I would recommend creating a `UserProfile` class with a one-to-one relationship to `User` where you can store this and other information.

See [this post](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html) for example of how to set that up.

Comment: so it would look something like what I have added to the original post in the updated section

Comment: @OmarJandali yep that's exactly what you want to do

Comment: @OmarJandali Instead of adding your update as an edit to my answer, it should be an edit to your question

Comment: @OmarJandali Your view needs to return a `Response` object. In the code you have posted, there is no return statement from your view.

Comment: when i return the response object from the search method, I get a message that says 'dict does not have the attribute client' which means that instead of returning the dict which the response object, i need to return the original response... or am I wrong?? @rawbeans

Comment: @OmarJandali your search method should not return a response object because it is not a view. Your linkBankLogin method is a view and needs to return a response object. The object can contain whatever you want, but usually for something like this it would contain the object that you modified. It can be empty if you would like though as you probably won't do anything with the contents of the response.